# Getting issue of `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-on-rails-6.1

```
   rails/railtie/configuration.rb:97:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer'
```

while updating from rails 4 to rails 6.0.1.

Previous version of ruby was 2.4
New Ruby version I am using is ruby 3.0.0

Comment: See the documentation: [**Upgrading Ruby on Rails**](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html). In general, the advice would be to upgrade one minor version at a time (4.0 --> 4.1 --> 4.2 --> 5.0 --> 5.1 --> 5.2 --> 6.0). Jumping from v4 to v6 in one leap is likely to fail in multiple ways, and it won't be obvious why / how to fix it.

Comment: Likewise, upgrading ruby from v2.4 to v3.0 in one big leap is likely to cause non-obvious pain! Rails 6 requires Ruby 2.5+, so perhaps it would be wise to postpone upgrading the ruby version beyond this until your other dependencies (especially rails) are modernised. Going up to ruby 2.7 should hopefully be straightforward, but the final step to 3.0 is more likely to cause challenges.

Comment: in the development.rb  file not detetcting config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors is causing issues.

Comment: My point was that you're likely going to encounter a long list of other such issues, and it's not going to be obvious how to resolve them. On the other hand, if you upgrade your application one minor version at a time - following the above linked documentation - it should be far more straightforward how to ensure everything is working as expected.